# Connection to Postgres Database using libpqxx

Tags: c++, libpqxx

I am using libpqxx to connect to a postgres database by creating a class.

```
class databaseConnection
{
public:
    pqxx::connection* conn;
    void SetConnection(){
        conn=new pqxx::connection(
            "username=temp "
            "host=db.corral.tacc.utexas.edu "
            "password=timelione "
            "dbname=temp");

    }

    void Disconnect(){
        conn->disconnect();
    }

    pqxx::result query(std::string strSQL){
        //SetConnection();
        pqxx::work trans(*conn,"trans");

        pqxx::result res=trans.exec(strSQL);

        trans.commit();
        return res;
    }
};

int main()
{
    databaseConnection* pdatabase;
    pdatabase->SetConnection();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error that says

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::broken_connection' 
what(): invalid connection option "database"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: @Gaurav has Daniel's answer helped you? If so please accept it. I'm faced with similar problems and if you don't accept it, most of us new users won't know if this is a solution or not. After all, he's taken the time to help you and you ought to say thanks in the least.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pgxx::connection(const PGSTD::string&)` is basically a wrapper around libpq's `PQconnectdb()` function, so the supported connection parameter keywords are the same as for libpq.

The parameter key word for the PostgreSQL user name to connect as is `user`, not `username`. Perhaps correcting that will fix the problem.

Also, in your sample code, `pdatabase` is an uninitialized pointer. You could either allocate a `databaseConnection` object on the stack with:

```
databaseConnection database;
database.SetConnection();
```

or use `new` to heap-allocate a `databaseConnection` object:

```
databaseConnection* pdatabase = new databaseConnection();
pdatabase->SetConnection();
```

But you need to pick one.

Answer (score 6):

if you try like this

```
try
{
    conn = new pqxx::connection(
    "username=temp "
    "host=db.corral.tacc.utexas.edu "
    "password=timelione "
    "dbname=temp");
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

it catches the exception about connection string:

```
invalid connection option "username"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to add `port=5432` to your connection string.